# Automorphism and Direct Product of Generating Set

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, graph-theory, finite-groups, graph-isomorphism

**Notation:**  $H $  are  partitioned into sub-graphs   $ H_1,H_2 \cdots H_x$  . We  see them in the  adjacency matrix of $H$  given below-

$$H = \begin{bmatrix}
H_{(x)} & R_{(x, x-1)} & R_{(x,x-2)} & \dots & \dots & R_{(x,1)} \\
R_{(x,x-1)} & H_{(x-1)} & R_{(x-1,x-2)} & \dots & \dots & R_{(x-1,1)} \\ \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \ddots & \vdots \\
R_{(x,1)} & R_{(x-1,1)} & R_{(x-2,1)} & \dots & \dots &H_{1} \end{bmatrix}$$

The adjacency matrix of graph $H_k \cup  H_e$ is $M_{(k,e)}$.  $M_{(k,e)} =\left( \begin{array}{ccc} H_e & R_{k,e} \\ R_{k,e}^{T} & H_k\\ \end{array} \right) $,  where, $R_{k,e}$ is the non symmetric sub-matrix of adjacency matrix $H$.  Each $H_k$ has constant number of vertices.

Set $\alpha_k$ is the set of  automrphism of $M_{(k,k+1)}$, i.e. $\alpha_k \subset Aut(M_{(k,k+1)})$ where $1 \leq k+1 \leq x$.

$\sigma$ is an automorphism  of graph $H$, i.e. $H^{\sigma}=H$ where $\sigma= \pi_1 \times \pi_2 \times .... \pi_x$ , i.e. $\sigma$ is a direct product of $\pi_1,  \pi_2 ,  .... \pi_x$.

**Question:**

***It is given that, $\pi_1,  \pi_2 ,  .... \pi_x$  exist as product of permutations/automorphisms  in corresponding $\alpha_1 , \alpha_2,...\alpha_x $ .***

For example,if $\pi_1 = \sigma_1 \times \tau_1$, then, $\alpha_1$ either has $\pi_1$ or both of $\sigma_1,  \tau_1$.

To obtain an automorphism of $H$, we construct direct prodect of all $\alpha_k$.

Is it correct? if not then why?